# How to describe a T that has bool Contains(T) method as an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I want to have an interface for behaviour similar to `string.Contains` say having a class representing stuff like RabbitMq tag. Say having `'1.222.3331.1'` and saying on it `.Contains(`122`)` get false and `.Contains(`1`)` get true.

I tried:

```
    interface ITag
    {
        bool Contains(ITag tag);
    }
```

Yet its implementation would limit `Contains` to work with `ITag` giving something like:

```
    class Tag : ITag
    {
        public bool Contains(ITag tag)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

while I would like to have for example :

```
    class Tag : ITag
    {
        public string s;
        public bool Contains(Tag other)
        {
            return s.Contains(other.s);
        }
    }
```

I wonder is what I described implementable as interface and how, Is there any out off box .Net interface that does `.Contains`?

Ofcourse I could do

```
    interface ITag<T>
    {
        bool Contains(T tag);
    }
```

and than implement it with something like:

```
    class Tag : ITag<Tag>
    {
        public Tag(string tag)
        {
            Content = tag;
        }

        public string Content { get; private set; }

        public bool Contains(Tag other)
        {
            return other != null 
                && other.Content != null
                && Content.Contains(other.Content);
        }
    }
```

Yet than I would need to make all my interfaces that use `ITag<T>` Generic and that is not desired. Is there a non generic way?

Comment: Your `Contains` method already works with all `ITags`? Or do you want it to always be the same class, so `Tag` has a `Tag` as parameter?

Comment: May be you could create tag's collection entity and implement ICollection interface?

Comment: There really isn't a non-generic compile-time way of doing what you're asking for. (Non-generic compile-time type constraint is *almost* an oxymoron considering generics are a fundamental pillar of the C# type system.) How is the compiler supposed to tell what type to allow to `Contains()` if you never tell it what's allowed?

Answer (score 3):

The following will compile:

```
interface ITag<in TTag> where TTag : ITag<TTag>
{
    bool Contains(TTag tag);
}

class Tag : ITag<Tag> 
{
    public bool Contains(Tag t)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That said, the whole construct just isn't very useful as opposed to just using the concrete type, since you always need to include that in the variable declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can create two interfaces `ITag` and `ITag<T>`, where the generic interface extends the non-generic interface like this:

```
public interface ITag
{
    bool Contains(ITag tag);
}

public interface ITag<T> : ITag
    where T : ITag<T>
{
    bool Contains(T tag);
}
```

Then in a class that implements `ITag<T>` I would do something like this:

```
public class Foo : ITag<Foo>
{
    public bool Contains(Foo tag) ...

    bool ITag.Contains(ITag tag)
    {
        Foo other = tag as Foo;
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return Contains(other);
    }
}
```